# Not getting mylocation

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-api-2

I am getting a problem with my map.It keep crashing whenever I try to get my location.it correctly display and open  when I use my own coordinates for my location.Whenever I remove the comment my program crashes.
Here is my log Cat.

```
01-26 13:34:49.609: E/dalvikvm(10290): Could not find class 'maps.ae.i', referenced from method maps.af.al.a
01-26 13:34:49.609: W/dalvikvm(10290): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 5490 (Lmaps/ae/i;) in Lmaps/af/al;
01-26 13:34:49.609: D/dalvikvm(10290): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0091
01-26 13:34:49.632: D/dalvikvm(10290): VFY: dead code 0x0093-00a0 in Lmaps/af/al;.a (Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;Z)Lmaps/af/al;
01-26 13:34:49.781: D/dalvikvm(10290): GC_CONCURRENT freed 343K, 41% free 4064K/6791K, external 598K/1110K, paused 3ms+5ms
01-26 13:34:50.070: D/dalvikvm(10290): GC_CONCURRENT freed 445K, 40% free 4283K/7111K, external 611K/1110K, paused 5ms+6ms
01-26 13:34:50.250: D/AndroidRuntime(10290): Shutting down VM
01-26 13:34:50.250: W/dalvikvm(10290): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
01-26 13:34:50.257: E/AndroidRuntime(10290): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 13:34:50.257: E/AndroidRuntime(10290): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pharmacyServices/com.example.pharmacyServices.Map}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-26 13:34:50.257: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
01-26 13:34:50.257: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-26 13:34:50.257: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-26 13:34:50.257: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-26 13:34:50.257: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 13:34:50.257: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-26 13:34:50.257: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-26 13:34:50.257: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 13:34:50.257: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-26 13:34:50.257: E/AndroidRuntime(10290):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
```

Code:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
// Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

try do this

```
public class MyBestLocation {
    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };
    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };
    //delay in seconds
    private int DELAY = 1;
    private Timer timer1;
    private LocationManager lm;
    private LocationResult locationResult;
    private boolean gps_enabled = false;
    private boolean network_enabled = false;
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result) {
        // przypisanie referencji
        locationResult = result;
        if (lm == null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // sprawdzam dostepnosc providerow
        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            network_enabled = lm
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        // jesli zaden nie jest dostepny wylaczam sie
        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if (gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    locationListenerGps);
        if (network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    locationListenerNetwork);
        //----------------------
       // async executor method upgrade
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), DELAY*2000);
       // ----------------

        // opozniam uruchomienie watku w celu odszukania lokacji jesli ktorys z
        // providerow zdola to zrobic
       /* scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);*/
        return true;
    }

    // Timer task sluzy do odszukania najmlodszej lokalizacji

    public static abstract class LocationResult {
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }

    /**
     * Klasa pomocnicza odpalana przez TimerTask.
     *
     * @author rafal.machnik
     */
    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

            Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null;
            if (gps_enabled)
                gps_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (network_enabled)
                net_loc = lm
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            // if there are both values use the latest one
            if (gps_loc != null && net_loc != null) {
                if (gps_loc.getTime() > net_loc.getTime())
                    locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                else
                    locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);

                return;
            }

            if (gps_loc != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);

                return;
            }
            if (net_loc != null) {
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);

                return;
            }
//          locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }

    }
```

To invoke it you only implement sth like that

```
   MyBestLocation bestLocation = new MyBestLocation();
                    if (bestLocation.getLocation(EditTask.this, locationResult)) {
                        locationResult.gotLocation(location);
                    }
```